# mov [ ], 's' в Assembler

Tags: ассемблер

Что означает вот этот надпись в Assembler:

```
mov [02h], 'H'

mov [04h], 'e'

mov [06h], 'l'

mov [08h], 'l'

mov [0ah], 'o'
```

Почему нельзя писать так:

```
mov 02h, 'H'

mov 04h, 'e'

mov 06h, 'l'

mov 08h, 'l'

mov 0ah, 'o'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Квадратные скобки - операция взятия адреса относительно текущего сегмента данных, или сегмента, указанного явно. Например:

```
mov [2], eax ; поместить по смещению 2 в сегменте ds значение eax (ds - сегмент данных)

mov byte cs:[edi], 1 ; поместить по смещению edi в сегмент cs единицу (один байт, cs - сегмент кода)

mov ss:[ebp+8], cx ; поместить в сегмент стека, по адресу ebp+8, значение cx

push [eax+edi*8] ; сохранить в стеке значение, которое 
                 ; находится в сегменте данных по смещению eax+edi*8

mov ecx, [var+eax] ; прочитать значение из сегмента данных по смещению var+eax
                   ;  (где var - адрес переменной) и поместить его в ecx
```

Такая же запись никакого смысла не имеет:

```
mov 02h, 'H'
```

02h - это просто числовая константа, в неё что-то записать нельзя.

---

Надо отметить, что в разных ассемблерах квадратные скобки могут иметь немного разный смысл. Например, если речь идёт о переменных (метках), то:

```
; -- MASM, TASM
; поместить в eax значение, находящееся по адресу var
; то же самое, что mov eax, [var]
mov eax, var

; -- NASM, FASM
; поместить в eax адрес переменной (метки) var
; то есть аналог mov eax, offset var / lea eax, var в TASM/MASM
mov eax, var
; НО!
mov [var], eax
mov eax, [var]
```

Comment: ds+2 и cs+edi дико режет глаз, ибо сегментные регистры в наше время (в защищенном режиме) никаких адресов не содержат и арифметика на них не действует, не зря двоеточие придумано ... думаю правильней было бы "по смещению 2 в сегменте ds"

Comment: ну да, формулировочка подкачала :)

Answer (score 0):

`02h` это число,
а `[02h]` это смещение

Comment: `offset` нужен когда нужно получить адрес (смещение) переменной (т.е. число вместо ссылки). Конструкция `offset 02h` не имеет особого смысла, потому что нельзя получить адрес числовой константы. Когда нужно записать число по какому-то адресу, то первым операндом пишется просто имя переменной или число в скобках (если говорить про TASM).

Comment: точно, забыл поправлю

Comment: Ну и первоначальный вариант тоже не совсем верен: смещение - это и есть число. `02h` - это просто число, но может быть интерпретировано как адрес (смещение), если по этому адресу обратиться через `[02h]`. `offset` - это как бы операция "снятия скобок", то есть, если переменная `var` находилась по адресу (смещению) `02h`, то `offset var` (смещение/адрес переменной) будет равно `02h`.